# Filter or search value when pages initially load in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, kendo-ui, pageload

I want to filtering the date range base when page loads and display it on the page.
the date is being autofill, my problem is is not able to filter it when using document ready in JQUERY, any thought ?

code:

```
                <label for="from">Start date:</label>

                <input type="text" style="width: 196px;" id="from" />

                <label for="to">End date:</label>

                <input type="text" style="width: 196px;" id="to" />

 //function for datepicker and date range


                $(function() {
                $("#from").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "-3w",
                    minDate: "-3w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                }).datepicker('setDate', '-3w');
                $("#to").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    maxDate: "currentText",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                    }
                }).datepicker('setDate', '+1w');
            });
```

function attemping....to fitler when  pages load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $filter = new Array();
                $from = new Date(Date.parse($("#from").datepicker('setDate', '-3w')));
                $to = new Date(Date.parse($("#to").datepicker('setDate', 'currentText')));
                $to = $to.setDate($to.getDate() + 1);

                if ($("#from").val()) {

                    $filter.push({ field: "DateEnrolled", operator: "islessthanorequalto", value: $to });
                }
                if ($("#to").val()) {

                    $filter.push({ field: "DateEnrolled", operator: "isgreaterthanorequalto", value: $from });
                }
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.load($filter);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did the updated example and fiddle not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grid.dataSource.filter($filter)
```

instead of

```
grid.dataSource.load($filter)
```

**Updated 11.02.2012**

[Here's a fiddle with what you're attempting to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/schapman/bxxYt/)

I made the filter take action on a button press instead of PageLoad so that you can see the data before and after the filter action.

You have to create a logical "and"  filter object and add your filters to that.

1) Create the "and" filter object

```
var customFilter = {
    logic: "and",
    filters: []
};
```

2) Add the filters to the object

```
customFilter.filters.push({
    field: "DOB",
    operator: "isgreaterthanorequalto",
    value: date1
});

customFilter.filters.push({
    field: "DOB",
    operator: "islessthanorequalto",
    value: date2
});
```

3) Set the filter on the grid's data source

```
$("#testGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter[customFilter]);
```

Sorry for the first answer being so lazy.  I was in a rush that day and just tried to get something up to help.  Hope this helps out better.

Comment: I just updated the answer to give a more thorough explanation.  Let me know if this doesn't work.